# Why choose EUC-JP over UTF-8 or SHIFT-JIS?

Tags: character-encoding, cjk, file-encodings

I've been working with a Japanese company who chooses to encode our files with EUC-JP.
I've been curious for quite a while now and tried asking superiors why EUC-JP over SHIFT-JIS or UTF-8, but get answers "like it's convention or such".
Do you know why the initial coders might have chosen EUC-JP over other character encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Shift-JIS, EUC-JP is ASCII-safe - any byte where the eigth bit is zero is ASCII. It was also historically popular in Unix variants. Either of these things could have been an important factor a long time ago before UTF8 was generally adopted. Check [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code#EUC-JP) for more details.